# I am able to change the innerHTML on my tic tac toe game via a restart button but once I restart I cannot reassign again to start the game

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot reassign my values once I click them and hit restart. Meaning if I put an X or a O in one of the tic tac toe boxes and hit restart, I will have the other boxes that I didn't hit in the last game available to play but the boxes that I hit in the last game will not show a value if I click them. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```js
const turn = document.getElementById('turn');
const restart = document.getElementById('restart');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('[data-index]');

let count = 1;

document.querySelector('.board').addEventListener('click', which);

function which(event) {
    console.log(`Index ${event.target.dataset.index} got clicked!`);

    if (count % 2 == 1 && event.target.classList.contains('unselected')) {
        count++
        event.target.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
        turn.innerHTML = "O Player's Turn";
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected');
        event.target.classList.remove('selectedX');
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0 && event.target.classList.contains('unselected')) {
        count++
        event.target.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-circle"></i>';
        turn.innerHTML = "X Player's Turn";
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected');
        event.target.classList.remove('selectedO');
    }
}

restart.addEventListener('click', newGame);

function newGame() {
    turn.innerHTML = "X Player's Turn";
    cells.forEach(e => {
        e.innerHTML = '';
    })
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
        
<header>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
</header>
<div class="turn" id='turn'>X Player's Turn</div>
<div class="board" id='board'>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='0'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='1'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='2'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='3'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='4'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='5'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='6'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='7'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='8'></div>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <button class="restart" id="restart">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const turn = document.getElementById('turn');
const restart = document.getElementById('restart');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('[data-index]');

let count = 1;

document.querySelector('.board').addEventListener('click', which);

function which(event) {
    console.log(`Index ${event.target.dataset.index} got clicked!`);

    if (count % 2 == 1 && event.target.classList.contains('unselected')) {
        count++
        event.target.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
        turn.innerHTML = "O Player's Turn";
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected');
        event.target.classList.remove('selectedX');
    }
    if (count % 2 == 0 && event.target.classList.contains('unselected')) {
        count++
        event.target.innerHTML = '<i class="far fa-circle"></i>';
        turn.innerHTML = "X Player's Turn";
        event.target.classList.remove('unselected');
        event.target.classList.remove('selectedO');
    }
}

restart.addEventListener('click', newGame);

function newGame() {
    turn.innerHTML = "X Player's Turn";
    cells.forEach(e => {
        e.innerHTML = '';
        e.classList.remove("selectedO","selectedX");
        e.classList.add("unselected");
    })
}
```

```css
.board {width:120px}
.box {display:inline-block;
      width:30px; height:30px;
      border: 1px solid gray; text-align:center}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
        
<header>
    <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
</header>
<div class="turn" id='turn'>X Player's Turn</div>
<div class="board" id='board'>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='0'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='1'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='2'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='3'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='4'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='5'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='6'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='7'></div>
    <div class="box unselected" data-index='8'></div>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    <button class="restart" id="restart">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Apart from adding a little (too little ...) CSS stuff I added the following lines to your `restart()` function:

```
 e.classList.remove("selectedO","selectedX");
 e.classList.add("unselected");
```

These are necessary to make the cells clickable again. Alternatively, I could have achieved the same with

```
 e.className="box unselected";
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason: You removed class 'unselected', so it would not get in the 2 `if`sections in function `which`

You could just check the value of it (check if value is empty)